# When using Weighted Estimating Equations (WEE) to estimate a linear regression model with missing data, what can do if missing probability is 1

Tags: estimation, missing-data

When using Weighted Estimating Equations (WEE) to estimate a linear regression model with missing data. One way is to assume the missing at random and then compute the missing probability using some regression models, such as logistic regression.

However, consider the case: We have independent samples $(Y_i,X_i),i=1,\ldots,n$, and there is another binary covariate $Z_i$ takes values on $\{0,1\}$. When $Z_i=0$ the $i$th observation is missing. This case means that the missing probability is either 0 or 1. Therefore the weights in WEE are not computable. What can we do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have no information about the relationship between $Y$ and $X$ when $Z=0$, so there's no estimation method that can save you. You either need better data or you need to realise you can only estimate the relationship between $Y$ and $X$ in the subpopulation where $Z=0$.